# Filtering dataframe based on date (keep only rows that occur 6 months after each other)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask you for help:
I have a dataframe which consists of 2 columns: ID and Month.
I would like to delete the rows where the ID is appearing before a 6 months time span.

For example, if customer ID 1 appears in month March I want him to appear only after 6 months, for example in September or later and I want to delete the rows in which my customer ID 1 appears before the 6 months time, for example in April.

Below an example of my dataset and the expected output.

[image: example-dataset-and-expected-output]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It isn't real clear from your example what you want.  You should expand your example to include other cases *and* just paste your example in the text of your question...not a picture.  Just paste it, highlight it, and select the "code sample" format which will indent it and format it as code in output.

Comment: It seems you want to "blank" or remove dates for each customer for 6 months after a record shows up... No?  What if the customer shows up *every* month...then your blanking algorithm depends on where you start.  Do you intend to iteratively do this starting at the **first** appearance?  Also, why are you using a data frame for this?  It would be 5x easier, and faster, with a different data structure like a dictionary